# ReSpeller is not checking TypeScript string interpolation

Tags: resharper, spell-checking

ReSpeller will identify the error in the first line but not the second line which is using TypeScript string interpolation.

```
    log.info('recieved');
    log.info(`recieved`);
```

Is there a configuration for ReSpeller that will enable these checks?
Since string interpolation is often customer facing it seems like that is an important part of sell checking.

I do realize that in this example that string interpolation is not necessary but the example is only to express the issue in the smallest code sample.